# Setters And Getters to different Class

Tags: java, for-loop

My problem is that, simply I don't know what code to use to get my value from my getX method to my other classses main method.

```
package hangman;
```

public class Hangman {

```
private int triesLimit;
private String word;

public void setTriesLimit(int triesLimit) {
    this.triesLimit = triesLimit;
}

public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}

public int getTriesLimit() {
    return this.triesLimit;
}

public String getWord() {
    return this.word;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return ("Enter Secret Word " + this.getWord()
            + ".\nEnter max # of tries (Must be under 7) "
            + this.getTriesLimit());
}
```

}

Thats from the sub-class and I am trying to store the value of the triesLimit into the main of this classes main method
package hangman;

```
public class PlayHangman {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hangman hangman = new Hangman();
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int triesCount = 0;
    int correctCount = 0;
    hangman.toString();
    int triesLimit = hangman.getTriesLimit();
    String secretWord = hangman.getWord();
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(secretWord.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
        b.append("*");
    }
    char[] secrectStrCharArr = secretWord.toCharArray();
    int charCnt = secretWord.length();
    for (int x = 0; triesCount < triesLimit; triesCount++) {
        while (charCnt >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Secrect Word :" + b.toString());
            System.out.println("Guess a letter :");

            char guessChar = scn.next().toCharArray()[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < secrectStrCharArr.length; i++) {
                if (guessChar == secrectStrCharArr[i]) {
                    b.setCharAt(i, guessChar);
                    correctCount++;
                } else if (guessChar != secrectStrCharArr[i]) {
                    triesCount++;
                    System.out.println("Incorrect: " + triesCount);hangmanImage(triesCount,correctCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried looking it up on here but couldn't find setters and getters used in a sub/superclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the class in the main method to access the variables and method available in that class like so

```
public class PlayHangman {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
       Hangman hangman = new Hangman();
       hangman.setTriesLimit(2)
        int value = hangman.getTriesLimit();

     }
```

You can look into static keyword to access the value directly but that requires a bit more understanding of OOP's and JAVA.
This should work fine.

Hope it helps :)

**EDITED**

ToString method is just to convert everything in your model class to String which you have done correctly,but you have implemented incorrectly.... Change your ToString content so

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ("The Secret Word you entered: " + this.getWord()
            + ".\n The max # of tries (Must be under 7): "
            + this.getTriesLimit());
}
```

You have initialized Scanner which does what you want, to ask the user to enter the values but again you haven't implemented it so add this to your main method

```
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
         hangman.setTriesLimit(scn.nextInt());
        hangman.setWord(scn.next());
       hangman.toString()//Will work now
```

Trial and error is your best friend now :)
and Google some of the issues rather than waiting for an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I thought you were only supposed to use that statement when your trying to make an object with multiple parameters/fields. Really appreciated!

Comment: haha no. Play around and you'll learn as you go along :) If it help solved your issue ensure that you select it as the right answers so that it will help other with similar issues

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. You've created a new `Hangman` object but it does not yet have a `triesLimit` set and `int triesLimit = ?` is invalid and will not compile.

Comment: @Zephyr He wanted to know why he wasn't able to get the setter and getter value ... for your sake I have modified the answer :P

Comment: This helped initially because now I know how to get the variables into the PlayHangman class but I am having issues with the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException". I think it has something to do with the toString method in the Hangman class. Any help? I have updated code in post

Comment: @anon you are right ToString is causing the issue ... why ?? because the values are still NULL ...hangman.getTriesLimit() andd ... so assign a value to them hangman.setTriesLimit(5) and hangman.setWord("game")

Comment: But a whole part of the program was to have the user enter the chosen word to be guessed, so would I have it as hangman.setWord(hangman.toString);?

Comment: @anon Unfortunately no... Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Like rohit said, this is as simple as understand the basics of OOP, specific the encapsulation.

If you want to get a little deeper into OOP patterns, you could use the Observer pattern. This allows you to change the status of any class instance, even if they're not related by inheritance, aggregation, etc.

You can scale the solution by making List of Observer

Your observable interface

```
public interface IObservable {
  // Set the observer
  public void setObserver(IObserver iObserver);

  // Notify the observer the current status
  public void notifyObserver();
}
```

Your observer interface

```
public interface IObserver {
  public void update(boolean status);
}
```

Your observer implementation

```
public class PlayHangman implements IObserver {
  private boolean status = false;

  public void printStatus() {
      System.out.println("Status: " + (this.status ? "Win" : "Lose"));
  }

  @Override
  public void update(boolean status) {
      // The instance status is updated
      this.status = status;
      // Print the current status
      this.printStatus();
  }
}
```

Your observable implementation

```
public class Hangman implements IObservable{
  private String goalWord = "";
  private String currentWord = "";
  private int triesLimit = 0;
  private int tries = 0;
  private IObserver iObserver;

  public Hangman(String goalWord, int triesLimit) {
      this.goalWord = goalWord;
      this.triesLimit = triesLimit;
  }

  public void setCurrentWord(String currentWord) {
      this.currentWord = currentWord;
      this.notifyObserver();
  }

  public void addTry() {
      this.tries++;
      this.notifyObserver();
  }

  @Override
  public void setObserver(IObserver iObserver) {
      this.iObserver = iObserver;
  }

  @Override
  public void notifyObserver() {
    // True = win
    this.iObserver.update(this.tries < this.triesLimit && 
    this.goalWord.equals(this.currentWord));
  }
}
```

Your Main class

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // PlayHangman (game status)
    PlayHangman playHangman = new PlayHangman();
    // Hangman initializes with a goalWord and the triesLimit
    Hangman hangman = new Hangman("HangmanJava", 5);
    // Set the observer
    hangman.setObserver(playHangman);
    // During the game you just can set the current word and add a try
    // You're not setting the status directly, that's the magic of the Observer pattern
    hangman.setCurrentWord("Hang");
    hangman.addTry();
    hangman.setCurrentWord("HangmanJava");
  }
}
```

Hope this helps and enjoy Java